# Using yii tabular form builder

Tags: php, yii

Am making a from in yii in a tabular from but the problem is that i cant control the form elements, They span the whole width despite of breaks

This is my code

```
$memberFormConfig = array(
'elements'=>array(
    'household_first_name'=>array(
        'type'=>'text',
        'maxlength'=>40,
    ),
    'household_middle_name'=>array(
        'type'=>'text',
    ),
    'household_surname'=>array(
        'type'=>'text',
        'maxlength'=>40,
    ),
    '<br>',
    'household_gender'=>array(
        'type'=>'dropdownlist',
        'items'=>array(''=>'-',0=>'Male',1=>'Female',),
    ),
    'household_participates_in_agric'=>array(
        'type'=>'dropdownlist',
        'items'=>array(''=>'-',0=>'yes',1=>'no',),
    ),
    'household_has_independent_activities'=>array(
        'type'=>'dropdownlist',
        'items'=>array(''=>'-',0=>'yes',1=>'no',),
    ),
    'household_hhrelation'=>array(
         'type'=>'dropdownlist',
        'items'=>$relations,
   ),
    'household_dob'=>array(
        'type'=>'zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
        'language'=>'de',
        'options'=>array(
            'showAnim'=>'fold',
        ),
    ),

));
```

This is the form configuration

```
$this->widget('ext.multimodelform.MultiModelForm',array(
//'validatedMembers' => $validatedMembers,
'id' => 'id_member', //the unique widget id
'formConfig' => $memberFormConfig, //the form configuration array
'tableView' => true,
'model' => $farmerform, //instance of the form model
'jsAfterNewId' => MultiModelForm::afterNewIdDatePicker($formConfig['elements']['dob']),
 ));
```

?>

This produces such a form
[image]

I would like it to be

[image]

That is adding breaks or form inputs controlling the width.. How do i do this